# Purity for algebraic De Rham complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, purity

Working with varieties over a field $k$ (you can assume it is $\mathbb{C}$ if necessary). Consider the truncated algebraic De Rham complex $\tau^{\leq n}\Omega_X^{\bullet}$ (This is the nice truncation not the brutal one). Given a closed immersion $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$ (Both are smooth) is there a way to calculate $i^!\tau^{\leq n}\Omega_X^{\bullet}$? (It most likely should be $(\tau^{\leq n-c}\Omega_Z^{\bullet})[-2c]$ where $c$ is the codimension of $Z$ in $X$.)

Edit: This follows if we assume the integral Bloch-Kato conjecture is true (Suslin's conjecture) since this holds for the morphic cohomology. On the other side if this is true for the truncated De Rham complex, the argument should somehow be more specific for the De Rham complex since this is not true in general (It is possible to give counter examples based on Motivic complexes).

Hartshorne proved that $i^!\Omega_X^{\bullet}=\Omega_Z^{\bullet}[-2c]$. The challenge that I am facing is that the methods of Hartshorne does not apply here (or I don't know how to make it work), because the truncated complex is not a complex of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, the last term is just a sheaf of abelian groups. So the method of turning the upper shriek to a pull-back by tensoring with relative canonical sheaf is not applicable here. I am not aware of anything similar for calculating the pullback in the derived category of sheaves, for complex algebraic varieties.

The only situations that I know you can reasonably calculate upper-shriek, are for sheaves on nice topological spaces, coherent sheaves on schemes and torsion etale sheaves on schemes.

Note: Another model for the truncated De Rham complex when the base field is the complex numbers is $\tau^{\leq n}R\alpha_*\mathbb{C}$, where $\alpha_*$ is the forgetful functor form the classical topology to the Zariski topology.

Comment: Are there any good properties for this truncation of the de Rham cohomology in char $0$? I know that in char $p$, there is the Cartier isomorphism, but I am not aware of any goodness of this truncation in char $0$.

Comment: @Z.M I am not sure what kind of goodness you are looking for. Can you prove this in char $p$ using the Cartier isomorphism?

Comment: I don't have experience of upper shriek. The point is that, in char $p$, the differentials are Frobenius linear, essentially because $\mathrm d(x^p)=0$. The associated pieces of the conjugate filtration are exactly the Frobenius twists of exterior powers of the Kähler differential, which seems to be easier to control.